# Controlled Frame Width Size In A Horizontal StackLayout

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a set of stacked horizontal StackLayouts composed of Frames with differing widths. The end goal is to create a Schedule View (multiple calendars viewed at once) not unlike what is possible in Outlook (see attached image).

Desired Output: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c0mu.png

In trying to do this I noticed that the Width of Frames added to a Horizontal StackLayout will match the WidthRequest only if all of the Frames have the same exact width. If the widths of the Frames differ then the Width and WidthRequests don't match.

Here is the XAML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="XamarinSample.SamplePage1">
    <ContentPage.Padding>
        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness" iOS="0, 20, 0, 0" />
    </ContentPage.Padding>
    <ScrollView x:Name="FrozenBandDataScrollView"  
        Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackLayout  VerticalOptions="Start"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            Spacing="0"
            BackgroundColor="Silver"
            WidthRequest="3600"
            x:Name="FrozenBandDataStackLayout">
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the Code:

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XamarinSample
{
    public partial class SamplePage1 : ContentPage
    {
        TapGestureRecognizer tapFrameRecognizer = new TapGestureRecognizer();

        public SamplePage1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            addDataPoints();
        }

        public void addDataPoints()
        {
            tapFrameRecognizer.Tapped += (s, e) =>
            {
                Frame f = s as Frame;
                Label l = f.Content as Label;
                l.Text = "R:" + f.WidthRequest;
                l.Text += ", W: " + f.Width;
                l.Text += "\nR: " + f.HeightRequest;
                l.Text += ", H: " + f.Height;
            };

            FrozenBandDataStackLayout.Children.Add(getStackLayoutWithDimensions(70, 3600));
            FrozenBandDataStackLayout.Children.Add(getStackLayoutWithDimensions(70, 3600));
            FrozenBandDataStackLayout.Children.Add(getStackLayoutWithDimensions(70, 3600));
        }

        public static double randomNumber(int start, int end){return (new Random()).Next(start, end);}

        public StackLayout getStackLayoutWithDimensions(double height, double width)
        {
            StackLayout sl = new StackLayout {
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                WidthRequest = width,
                HeightRequest = height,
                Spacing = 0
            };

            //OPTION 1: randomly calculated width (total = 3600) -- does not work :(
            int minFrameWidth = 1;
            int maxFrameWidth = 500;
            double currentWidth = 0;
            while ((currentWidth + maxFrameWidth) < width)
            {
                double frameWidth = randomNumber(minFrameWidth, maxFrameWidth);
                currentWidth += frameWidth;
                sl.Children.Add(getFrameWithDimensions(height, frameWidth));
            }
            sl.Children.Add(getFrameWithDimensions(height, width-currentWidth));

            //OPTION 2: specific homogeneous width (total = 3600) -- works :)
            /*
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                sl.Children.Add(getFrameWithDimensions(height, 300));
            }
            */

            //OPTION 3: specific altering width (total = 3600) -- does not work :(
            /*
            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    sl.Children.Add(getFrameWithDimensions(height, 200));
                }else
                {
                    sl.Children.Add(getFrameWithDimensions(height, 400));
                }
            }
            */

            return sl;
        }

        public Frame getFrameWithDimensions(double height, double width)
        {
            Frame frame = new Frame
            {
                BackgroundColor = Color.Gray,
                OutlineColor = Color.Black,
                HasShadow = false,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                WidthRequest = width,
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Start,
                HeightRequest = height,
                Content = new Label
                {
                    HorizontalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalTextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    TextColor = Color.Black,
                    FontFamily = "Arial",
                    FontSize = 8,
                    Text = "test"
                }
            };
            frame.GestureRecognizers.Add(tapFrameRecognizer);
            return frame;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the three different outputs: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/74391/controlled-frame-width-size-in-a-horizontal-stacklayout

Does anyone know a way to assure that the WidthRequest matches the actual Width?

Also, can anyone think of another possible Xamarin Forms solution? I've tried using a Grid but it was really slow (as it's not meant for this type of use). It would be nice to have something with data binding like a horizontal ListView.

Note: This app would need to work for iOS, Windows UWP, and possibly Android.

Comment: this question and 0 answers in 3 years. well, I hope you did choose to go native in the meantime..